# How properly update css with new custom css to avoid double load?

Tags: javascript, php, css

I hope that someone can help me about this problem. For example how to avoid double loading ? For example if user selects custom google font for H1, page first loads standard font and then custom font.... and then you see double loading....

and the same problem is also if user input custom css style for something and then again double loading....

plesae tell me which technique is used to avoid such things ?

Thank you

Comment: what is this double loading

Comment: maybe OP meant double rendering. one with normal font and then again with custom font.

Comment: I think @Mr_Green is correct.  When you load a font on-the-fly you get a view of the page for a second or so without it, and then the page updates when the font has been downloaded.  Hiding things and pre-loading the font is the answer - OP investigate that.

Comment: do you mean this: [image css](http://imgur.com/a/YUQ1n) with double loading?

Comment: yes,  I thought double rendering

Comment: but not only for fonts, but in general for custom css

Comment: You can't avoid it. As soon as you change, load, or update the CSS, the browser **will** re-render it. (at least in my experience)

Comment: How ? for example, i have site with wordpress installed. and in options page when i insert new css style for example for header. after that it does not double render... it just uses new style for header and other from standard css...